# Capturing mousedown event on HTML button when button "pressed" by key

Tags: javascript, button, dom-events

If I set up a `mousedown` event in Javascript for a button, it fires when I press down on the button.  If I set up a click event, it fires when I release the button.  So I can keep notified of the state of the button at all times.  However, if the button is "pressed" using the keyboard (e.g. by using tab to select the button, and then pressing the space bar to press the button) I don't get any event.  However, when I release the space bar I do get the click event.

It appears that I can attach a key event to the button, and then by looking at the key pressed and making sure it is the space bar I can simulate the `mousedown`, that is, I can tell that the button is pressed.  But this assumes that the space bar is the key being pressed; on another browser or OS this may not be the case.  I suppose I could simply check if the button is up or down, but then I have to maintain some state that I share with the mouse event, otherwise the mouse might have already pressed the button and an unrelated key hit while the mouse is down.

I haven't found anything that specific says how to handle this condition.  I have tried the change event, but it never fires.  Ideally I would like a single event that is fired whenever the state of the button changes, regardless of how it changes.  Or, having two separate events, one when the state changes to pressed, and one when the state changes to unpressed, would also be acceptable, as I can combine them to emulate the former.

Comment: @MrJack I'm interested in how to do it without jquery

Comment: JQuery is opensource, you could just download the dev. version and go to that specific function, that is what I meant, but when re-reading I sounded like something else.

Comment: understood. in general i prefer to avoid jquery answers, because it first presumes that jquery does exactly what i am trying to do (i'll probably have to do extra work to confirm that it does) and then if it does i'll have to dig in to figure out how it is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Example not using jquery:

```
<html><body>
<button id="mybutton">Click or press</button>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function buttonDown(button) {
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "button " + button.id + " pressed";
}
function buttonUp(button) {
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "button " + button.id + " released";
}
var b = document.getElementById("mybutton");
b.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var code = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if (code == 32 || code == 13) { // enter or space
    buttonDown(this);
  }
});
b.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var code = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if (code == 32 || code == 13) { // enter or space
    buttonUp(this);
  }
});
b.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var button = e.which || e.button;
  if (e.button == 0) { // left click
    buttonDown(this);
  }
});
b.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var button = e.which || e.button;
  if (e.button == 0) { // left click
    buttonUp(this);
  }
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Looks good, but is there any kind of guarantee or even guideline that enter or space are the only character codes that correspond to the button being pressed, or any cases where they would not generate the button press?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this will work for all cases where enter/space are pressed/released when the button has focus, regardless of browser or operating system.  I don't believe any other keypress typically triggers buttons, but if there was such a case you would determine the keycode and adjust the event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

## UPDATE

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKY44/) for a demo.

Example:

```
$('input').on('keydown mousedown', function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    alert('rawr!');
    if(code == 13)
    {
        alert('Enter key pressed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: but mouse events don't fire when the button is pressed using the keyboard

Comment: So you bind `.onmousedown` and `.onkeypress` to the same function

Comment: no, because as i mentioned originally, there is no guarantee that the key event is actually causing the button to be pressed.  (also, i think it would be onkeydown, not onkeypress)

Comment: There are three: `.onkey` `press`, `down` and `up`. And yes, you just ask in the function if the key being pressed is the "enter" key and if so, perform the function

Comment: Please see [link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) for a listing of key codes. P.S. "enter" is "13" ;)

Comment: "space" (spacebar) is 32 I believe. See my updated answer for an example of keyCode checking.